# Hive - issues on starting using hadoop 2.7.3 and derby

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, derby

**Exception:**

> Logging initialized using configuration in
>   jar:file:/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-common-2.1.0.jar!/hive-log4j2.properties
>   Async: true Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:578)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.beginStart(SessionState.java:518)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:705)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:641)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136) Caused by:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:226)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.(Hive.java:366)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.create(Hive.java:310)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getInternal(Hive.java:290)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.get(Hive.java:266)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:545)
>     ... 9 more Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to
>   instantiate
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1627)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:130)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:101)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3317)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3356)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3336)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllFunctions(Hive.java:3590)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.reloadFunctions(Hive.java:236)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:221)
>     ... 14 more Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1625)
>     ... 23 more Caused by: javax.jdo.JDOFatalInternalException: Error
>   creating transactional connection factory NestedThrowables:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:671)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:834)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.createPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:338)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:217)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   javax.jdo.JDOHelper$16.run(JDOHelper.java:1965)   at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invoke(JDOHelper.java:1960)   at
>   javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1166)
>     at
>   javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:808)
>     at
>   javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:701)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPMF(ObjectStore.java:424)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPersistenceManager(ObjectStore.java:453)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initialize(ObjectStore.java:327)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:294)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:76)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.(RawStoreProxy.java:58)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.getProxy(RawStoreProxy.java:67)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStore(HiveMetaStore.java:581)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:546)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:612)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:398)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.(RetryingHMSHandler.java:78)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:84)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:6396)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:236)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:70)
>     ... 28 more Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.createExecutableExtension(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:606)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.createExecutableExtension(PluginManager.java:330)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.store.AbstractStoreManager.registerConnectionFactory(AbstractStoreManager.java:203)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.store.AbstractStoreManager.(AbstractStoreManager.java:162)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.(RDBMSStoreManager.java:284)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.createExecutableExtension(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:606)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.createExecutableExtension(PluginManager.java:301)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.NucleusContextHelper.createStoreManagerForProperties(NucleusContextHelper.java:133)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.PersistenceNucleusContextImpl.initialise(PersistenceNucleusContextImpl.java:420)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:821)
>     ... 57 more Caused by: org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusException:
>   Attempt to invoke the "BONECP" plugin to create a ConnectionPool gave
>   an error : The specified datastore driver
>   ("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver") was not found in the CLASSPATH.
>   Please check your CLASSPATH specification, and the name of the driver.
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl.generateDataSources(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:232)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl.initialiseDataSources(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:117)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl.(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:82)
>     ... 75 more Caused by:
>   org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.connectionpool.DatastoreDriverNotFoundException:
>   The specified datastore driver ("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver")
>   was not found in the CLASSPATH. Please check your CLASSPATH
>   specification, and the name of the driver.    at
>   org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.connectionpool.AbstractConnectionPoolFactory.loadDriver(AbstractConnectionPoolFactory.java:58)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.connectionpool.BoneCPConnectionPoolFactory.createConnectionPool(BoneCPConnectionPoolFactory.java:54)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl.generateDataSources(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:213)
>     ... 77 more

**hive-site.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
  <value>jdbc:derby:;databaseName=/usr/local/hive/metastore_db;create=true</value>
  <description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
  <value>org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver</value>
  <description>Driver class name for a JDBC metastore</description>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Replace value of `javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName` with `org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver`

or

2) Add `http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/derby/derbyclient/10.10.1.1/derbyclient-10.10.1.1.jar` in `hive-client/lib` path

and try again

Comment: Thank you ! 
all is ok but hive is not started on hadoop master
derby.log file contains following lines
`Fri Oct 07 17:00:08 PKT 2016:
Booting Derby version The Apache Software Foundation - Apache Derby -$
on database directory /usr/local/hive/metastore_db with class loader $
Loaded from file:/usr/local/hive/lib/derby-10.10.2.0.jar
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.runtime.version=1.7.0_60-b19
user.dir=/usr/local/hive
os.name=Linux
os.arch=amd64
os.version=2.6.32-642.1.1.el6.x86_64
derby.system.home=null
Database Class Loader started - derby.database.classpath=''
`

Comment: Check this link 
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveDerbyServerMode in case you missed any step

Comment: can we use mongodb rather then derby for hive ?

Comment: I dont think so. It is Nosql db.
Try MySql metastore

Comment: Have you checked `/var/log/hive/` for any logs. What happens when you type `hive` in command line?

Comment: If you're using the Derby `EmbeddedDriver` JDBC Driver, then you should put `derby.jar`, not `derbyclient.jar`, into your CLASSPATH